# How to state commands of 'animation stop animating'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio, animation

I have an app I'm creating and I need some help. Under the view did load I have a code to play music which is fine. Then there is button saying 'play' when they click play the music STOPS and a animation starts. Now after the animation finished 2 buttons appear. How would I state animation stop animating like a void or ibaction so then I can put when the animation stop animating happens play the music again. If this dosent make sense please feel free to ask questions, Im a beginner so take it easy on me :) thanks

Comment: Do you want to call a method once the animation is finish?

Comment: abc's answer is the way to go, make sure you accept the answer and up vote it

Comment: Hello I have tried ADC's code but I don't know where to put it, in the inaction of play or after it? because if it put it in the ibaction it says its undeclared identifier and if i put it after it doesn't have any }'s meaning any code after it gets lots of errors?

Comment: The method is animateWith....so replace tou current animation starting code line with adc's. Its just a variation of the method which triggers ur animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations 
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Would allow you to know when an animation is completed, code in the completion block will be executed when the animation finishes.

Comment: Sorry should I put the code under IBACTION press play after the animation? Because it says its an undeclared identifier??